# c++ code convert in python with ctypes and mmap

Tags: c++, python-3.x, cython, ctypes, debian-jessie

I am trying to convert c++ code into python.

```
int fd_vdma = open("/dev/mem", O_RDWR|O_SYNC);  // open uiox device for vdma access
    if (fd_vdma < 1) {
        printf("Invalid mem device file\n");
    }
    // mmap the vdma device for vdma access

    unsigned int *ptr_vdma;
    ptr_vdma = (unsigned int*)mmap(NULL, VDMA_MAP_SIZE,PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, 
    MAP_SHARED, fd_vdma, VDMA_ADDR);
    printf("DMA 1 virtual address: 0x%08x \n",ptr_vdma);

    *(ptr_vdma+5) = FRBUF_ADDR_0;
    *(ptr_vdma+7) = 2;  // use internal fifos to trigger xfer
    *(ptr_vdma+8) = 20480;
    *(ptr_vdma+6) = (75 << 16) + (HORIZ_PIXELS_SMALL+75);
    *(ptr_vdma+0x0D) = 200;  // no. FIFO threshhold .. max.. 240
```

I have done so far,

```
# vdm memory check
try:
    fd_vdm_path = "/dev/mem"
    mode = "rb+"
    fd_vdm =  open(fd_vdm_path, mode)
    # print(fd_vdm.fileno())
    print("[INFO] " + fd_vdm_path + " checked")

except Exception as error:
    print("{}".format(error))

 # mmap the VDMA device for VDM access
vdma_buf = mmap.mmap(fd_vdm.fileno(), int(VDMA_MAP_SIZE), 
mmap.MAP_SHARED, mmap.PROT_READ|mmap.PROT_WRITE, 0)

ptr_vdm = ctypes.c_uint.from_buffer(vdma_buf)
print(type(ctypes.addressof(ptr_vdm)))
print("[INFO] " + fd_vdm_path + " has allocated virtual address : " + 
hex(ctypes.addressof(ptr_vdm)))
```

but I have stuck here, I do not know how to perform below operations in python.

```
*(ptr_vdma+5) = FRBUF_ADDR_0;
*(ptr_vdma+7) = 2;  // use internal fifos to trigger xfer
*(ptr_vdma+8) = 20480;
*(ptr_vdma+6) = (75 << 16) + (HORIZ_PIXELS_SMALL+75);
*(ptr_vdma+0x0D) = 200;  // no. FIFO threshhold .. max.. 240
```

I have tried to `vdma_buf.write(FRBUF_ADDR_0)` but it is not working and I could not find anything on the internet (possibly I did not search it well)
can you please help with this problem or else suggest me some links or tutorials?

Comment: My Python is tragically weak, but you may be able to take advantage of `*(ptr_vdma+5)` being identical to `ptr_vdma[5]`.

Comment: I tried it earlier, it throws an error called `TypeError: 'c_ulong' object does not support item assignment`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `memoryview` and `struct.pack`:

```
...
mm = memoryview(vdma_buf)

mm[5*4:6*4] = struct.pack("I", FRBUF_ADDR_0)
mm[7*4:8*4] = struct.pack("I", 2)
mm[8*4:9*4] = struct.pack("I", 20480)
mm[6*4:7*4] = struct.pack("I", (75 << 16) + (HORIZ_PIXELS_SMALL+75))
mm[0x0D*4:0x0E*4] = struct.pack("I", 200)
```

memoryview represents sequence of bytes, and if you want to write some other type to memory, you must convert it to bytes using `struct.pack`.

So, let's say you want to to write an unsigned int at index **N**.
First, you call `struct.pack("I", ...)` to get int's byte representation. Then you must calculate destination memory address. Because unsigned int's size is 4 bytes, the address is equal to **N*4**.

memoryview supports **slicing** so you can just write:

```
mm[StartAddress:EndAddress] = BytesYouWantToWrite
```

where StartAddress is equal to N*4 and EndAddress is (N+1) * 4

Comment: when I use memoryview, it throws an error called `TypeError: cannot make memory view because the object does not have the buffer interface` Am I doing mmap wrong? or I need to do some step before using memoryview?

Comment: Do you use python 3? This error shows up in python 2.7 : https://bugs.python.org/issue9229

Comment: I am sorry, I am using a virtual environment and I was not in the virtual environment. that why I had that error. but even in python3, I am getting this error ValueError: memoryview: invalid value for formate 'B' , when i am using mm[5]= FRBUF_ADDR_0 (FRBUF_ADDR_0 = 0x1E000000) , seems like i can write only limited values (0xff) in the buffer.

Comment: Actually it was my original answer, which was not corecct. See updated version.

Comment: thank you very much, it works like a charm, but would you mind explain it a little?

Comment: I've added some explanation, hope it;s more clear now.

Comment: thank you very much, it is perfect, I have been trying to solve this problem for 3 days and you have done so easily.